# I have MS Office 2010 64 bit SP2 which I would like to install on Ubuntu 14.04, how do I go about doing that?

Tags: 14.04, wine, 64-bit

I have MS Office 2010 64 bit SP2 (from my university) which I would like to install on Ubuntu 14.04, how do I go about doing that?

I have Wine 1.6 (not sure if there is a specific -bit version I need) as well as PlayOnLinux

Regards

Comment: I was successful in getting MS Office 2010 to install on 14.04 with Wine. It kind of only halfway worked though.

Comment: The way I got it to work was via PlayOnLinux. Don't have high expectations. Just be glad if it kind of works. I like Libreoffice. Same functionality, maybe even more robust in some areas.

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of using MS Office you can instead try WPS Office(A decent MS Office clone made by Kingsoft).It's free and best of all you don't even have to use Wine in order to run it!.I easily recommend it over LibreOffice as it has the ribbon interface and excellent compatibility with MS Office documents.If you want to try it the Linux version of WPS Office should be found here http://wps-community.org/download.html